# NFS4 & VirtualBox: Ubuntu 14.04 host Windows 10 Techpreview client

Tags: ubuntu, windows, nfs, ubuntu-14.04

I have a host OS Ubuntu 14.04 (my main OS). I run a Windows 10 client inside VirtualBox.

I wish for NFS4 to work between them, I cannot see the share in my Windows 10 client. I followed the following tutorial for my Ubuntu: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04

I can ping from the client to host and host to client via their ip addresses, but not via their hostname. Windows firewall is also fully disabled in Windows 10. Windows 10 client is also set on a bridged adapter and not NAT.

- Host ip: 192.168.1.108
- Client ip: 192.168.1.120

Both have same gateway.

Comment: What are you using to mount the NFS share?

Comment: @heavyd Oh I must utilize a client program for it to work? That seems, weird. Anything you suggest (any free which support NFS4? I used nekodrive but that hasn't been updated since 2011 and only supports NFS3).

Comment: I honestly don't have much experience with NFS clients.  I know that the Enterprise/Ultimate versions of Windows can install a client with the Services for Unix.  You could also look at [this client from the University of Michigan](http://citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/).